# PHP: Convert INSERT MySQLi to PDO

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm new in PDO programming. Based on my question, can anyone help me to convert MySQLi to PDO? Below is the code:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

$photo_before = $_POST['photo_before'];
$report_id = $_GET["report_id"] ?? "";

$sql_query = "UPDATE report SET photo_before ='$photo_before', time_photo_before = NOW(), ot_start = '16:00:00' WHERE report_id = '$report_id'";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query))
{
    echo "Data Save!";
}
else
{
    echo "Error!! Not Saved".mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
```

Hope there's a kind people to help me. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please **attempt something** then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Also, please be aware that you should **NEVER** use user input like `$_POST` directly in SQL statements (even when mapped to variables)! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding your `$_POST` variables to parameters. Given your code above, you have a **serious** security vulnerability. You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: 1. Are you using POST and GET? 2. Do you want to switch to PDO, or use mysqli with prepared statements? 3. The code you presented is for an update, do you require it as an insert or what is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PDO` as this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase;charset=utf8mb4";
$options = [
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // turn off emulation mode for "real" prepared statements
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //turn on errors in the form of exceptions
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, //make the default fetch be an associative array
];
try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "username", "password", $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit();
}
```

and prepared statements:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE report SET photo_before =?, time_photo_before = NOW(), ot_start = '16:00:00' WHERE report_id = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['photo_before'],$_GET["report_id"] ?? ""]);
```

Comment: Just a quick heads up: 1. there is no point in using a transaction for a single query. 2. There is no point for a random code part to say something like 'Something weird happened'. Such a message must be uniform for all occasions and written in a single place, not scattered around the code. so it's better to leave PDOException alone

Comment: @YourCommonSense I thought it’s always better to show best practices so that people can access the answers and edit their code accordingly. But for the most part I agree. The example that I showed was overloaded. I have corrected.

Answer (score -5):

You can insert like this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE report SET photo_before =?, time_photo_before = NOW(), ot_start = '16:00:00' WHERE report_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param($photo_before,$report_id);

// set parameters and execute
$photo_before = "value";
$report_id = "value";
$stmt->execute();
```

Hope this will work for you and in case you need the source https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: There are still a few error after you edit your answer: 1) PDO doesn't have connect_error property 2) bind_param should be bindParam

Comment: @catcon Nope, not an array, but this answer merges PDO and mysqli. A PDO object would call it as `placeholder name, parameter name, string type`.

Comment: @user3783243: ah thanks, after a quick search, I think I am confused between `bindParam()` and `execute()`

Comment: The `execute` can bind a value so `bindvalue` isn't really needed. `bindparam` binds a parameter.