# How to insert Multiple Checkbox in different column in Database

Tags: php, html

I have some problem here where I could not get a single value from my multiple checkbox. I want to stored it in different column for each tick value=1, the box does not tick is 0 in database.For normal input I get the value but does not work on checkbox. Could you guys help.

HTML Code: This my html code

```
<div class="col-sm-4">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="colour">Machine</label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="input_1">
                    </div><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Inspection[]" value="true"> Function<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Inspection[]" value="true"> Visual<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Inspection[]" value="true"> Sleeve<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Inspection[]" value="true"> Mail<br>

    </div>
<p><input type="button" id="add_btn" value="Save"></p>
```

JavaScript: Where I should get the value and store it in database.

```
$(document).on("click", "input#add_btn", function() { Addsave() });

function  Addsave()
{

    var Inspec1 = $("#input_1").val();
    var Inspec2 = $("input[name='Inspection']:checked").val();
    var Inspec3 = $("input[name='Inspection']:checked").val();
    var Inspec4 = $("input[name='Inspection']:checked").val();
    var Inspec5 = $("input[name='Inspection']:checked").val();

    var tables = ["example"];

    var AddObject = new Object();


        AddObject.column1    = Inspec1;
        AddObject.column2    = Inspec2;
        AddObject.column3    = Inspec3;
        AddObject.column4    = Inspec4;
        AddObject.column5    = Inspec5;


    var list = [AddObject];
    var objParams = JSON.stringify(list);

    var render  = function(){ renderAddExec(data);};
    insertExecute(list,tables,render);
}
```

Yesterday I found this in here stackoverflow but everytime I try, it does not work.

```
<?php

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

$checkBox = $_POST['Inspection'];

if(isset($_POST['add_btn']))
{
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox); $i++)
        {
            $query="INSERT INTO example (column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES ('" . $checkBox[$i] . "')";     

            mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
        }
    echo "Complete";

}

?>
```

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider upgrading your PHP and switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: In addition to this, your `name` is `Inspection`, and yet you are checking for a `$_POST` of `Days`, which is never set.

Comment: Also, to the question mentioned above, you set the value of all checkboxes to ‘true’ you have to consider give them appropriate names, even if you not use them when storing. Again use proper form of embedding this values in to your sql query.

Comment: I'm sorry I already re-edit it, `Days` is because I do some testing a lot with using simple form to test it but even the simple one could get the input maybe @Obsidian is correct I will try another way using PDO perhaps.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I set the value to `true` because I want the value insert to different column of table each checkbox have their own column they are not mean to be in same column.

Comment: Checkboxes are not submitted unless they are checked, so consider naming them other than array, like <input type="checkbox" name="**visual**" value="true">, this way you can handle them with no problems.

Comment: What's the status of the question? Have answers given solve it?

Comment: Yeah, I already solve ,thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

1. Your checkboxes has never been executed, because you check
   `if(isset($_POST['add_btn']))` but your submit button does not have
   any name, this is just ID.
2. You use `JQuery` to create object which
   need to be submitted. You spread this in to 3 functions, when it can
   be done with just calling `ajax` if you need `async`.

*I did tested out on my localhost your code with pure php and it works like it should.*

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
                <div class="col-sm-4">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="colour">Machine</label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="input_1">
                    </div><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Inspection[]" value="true"> Function<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Inspection[]" value="true"> Visual<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Inspection[]" value="true"> Sleeve<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Inspection[]" value="true"> Mail<br>

                </div>
            <!-- I added a name to button to catch the event on backend -->
            <p><input name="submit" type="submit" id="add_btn" value="submit"></p>
            </form>
```

**post.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['Inspection']))
    {
        var_dump($_POST['Inspection']);
        foreach($_POST['Inspection'] as $val)
        {
            echo $val;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'true' (length=4)
  1 => string 'true' (length=4)
  2 => string 'true' (length=4)
  3 => string 'true' (length=4)
truetruetruetrue
```

My solution to your code using PDO:

```
if($_POST()) //For debug check if it was post request
{
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox); $i++)
        {
            $stmt=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO example (column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");     

            $stmt->execute($_POST['Inspection']);//array(true,true,true,true)
        }
    echo "Complete";

}
```

How to convert mysql to PDO check this link:
[PHP: Convert INSERT MySQLi to PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132158/php-convert-insert-mysqli-to-pdo/59132237?noredirect=1#comment104493775_59132237)

Comment: @Triby If , let's say 2 checkboxes are checked, at the end you get this array `[true,true]` which will trigger PDO Exepcion. I suggest or to use `JQuery` to check if checkbox was checked then assign a value, otherwise assign false, to get proper field order of assignment.